# How can I merge each two lines of a large text file into a Python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a .txt file that is split into multiple lines, but each two of these lines I would like to merge into a single line of a list. How do I do that?

Thanks a lot!

What I have is organized like this:

```
[1 2 3 4

5 6]

[1 2 3 4

5 6 ]
```

while what I need would be:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6]

[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Comment: You can make your question better by adding what you've tried already. The code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things here:

1) If the text file was created by writing using numpy's savetxt function, you can simply use numpy.loadtxt function with appropriate delimiter.

2) Read file in a string and use a combination of replace and split functions.

```
file = open(filename,'r')
dataset = file.read()
dataset = dataset.replace('\n',' ').replace('] ',']\n').split('\n')
dataset = [x.replace('[','').replace(']','').split(' ') for x in dataset]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data =[]
with open(r'<add file path here >','r') as file:
    x = file.readlines()

    for i in range(0,len(x),2):
        data.append(x[i:i+2])
new =[' '.join(i) for  i in data]
for i in range(len(new)):
    new[i]=new[i].replace('\n','')
new_file_name = r'' #give new file path here
with open(new_file_name,'w+') as file:
    for i in new:
        file.write(i+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
final_data = []
with open('file.txt') as a:
    fdata= a.readlines()
    for ln in range(0,len(fdata),2):
        final_data.append(" ".join([fdata[ln].strip('\n'), fdata[ln+1].strip('\n')]))

print (final_data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried but still I get something like [ ' [1 2 3 4 5 6] ' , ' [1 2 3 4 5 6] ' , ... ] and it doesn't look like a regular list.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you can use a regex for solving this scenario :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7
import re

with open("textfilename.txt") as r:
     text_data = r.read()
independent_lists = re.findall(r"\[(.+?)\]",r ,re.DOTALL)
#now that we have got each independent_list we can next work on
#turning it into a list
final_list_of_objects = [each_string.replace("\n"," ").split() for each_string in independent_lists]
print final_list_of_objects
```

However if you do not want them to be as a list object and rather just want the outcome without the newline characters inbetween the list then:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7
import re

with open("textfilename.txt") as r:
     text_data = r.read()
new_txt = ""
for each_char in text_data:
     if each_char == "[":
        bool_char = True
     elif each_char == "]":
        bool_char = False
     elif each_char == "\n" and bool_char:
        each_char = " "
     new_txt += each_char
new_txt = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", new_txt) # to remove multiple space lines between numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
    new_data =  (" ".join(line.strip() for line in file).replace('] ',']\n').split('\n')) # ['[1 2 3 4  5 6]', ' [1 2 3 4  5 6 ]']


with open('test.txt','w+') as file:
    for data in new_data:
        file.write(data+'\n')
```

> **line.rstrip()** removes just the trailing newline(**'\n'**) from the line.
>
> you need to pass all read and stripped lines to **' '.join()**, not
>   each line itself. Strings in python are sequences to, so the string
>   contained in line is interpreted as separate characters when passed on
>   it's own to ' '.join().